# How to assign a function to state in constructor?

Tags: reactjs

I need to access a function through React's context API, because I have two distantly related components in terms of rendering location that are closely linked in data exchange.

The best strategy is to use React's context api (not using redux yet). I would normally pass the functions as props, but I need to access them through the context. I've defined the functions in the context, and I need to assign them to state in the constructor. Is there any way to do this, or should I use .setState in componentDidMount?

Right now setting state in componentDidMount is working, I'm not sure that this is the correct way. My context provider class shows the functions I'm trying to set in context state. 
Here is my context provider class:

```
import React from 'react';

const AppContext = React.createContext();



class AppProvider extends React.Component{
  state = {
    user: this.props.user,
    songs: [],
    nowPlaying: {},
    ended: false,
    paused: false,
    onPlaying: '',
    onEnd: '',
    onPausing: '',
    onSetSongs: ''
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
      user: this.props.user,
      onPlaying: this.handlePlaying,
      onEnd: this.handleEnd,
      onPausing: this.handlePausing,
      onSetSongs: this.handleSetSongs
    });
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
    return {user: props.user}
  }

  handleSetSongs = (songs) => {
    this.setState({songs});
  }

  handlePlaying = (song) => {
    this.setState({
      nowPlaying: song,
      ended: false,
      paused: false});
  }

  handlePausing = () => {
    if(this.state.paused){ this.handlePlaying(this.state.nowPlaying); }
    else{ this.setState({paused: true}) }
  }


  handleEnd = () => {
    var currentId = this.state.nowPlaying.idSongs;
    var index = this.state.songs.findIndex(function(song){ return song.idSongs === currentId; });
    var nextSong = this.state.songs[index+1];

    if(nextSong){ this.handlePlaying(nextSong); }
    else{ return }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export {
  AppProvider,
  AppContext
};
```

Comment: Can you at least post some code of yours? What are the functions, how components are connected?

Comment: the way children components are related isn't so important in this case, they're so distant that i have to use either context or redux, but here is the context class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not set functions to state, since they are most likely not to be changed. You can simply pass them like

```
render() {
    const handlers = {
      onPlaying: this.handlePlaying,
      onEnd: this.handleEnd,
      onPausing: this.handlePausing,
      onSetSongs: this.handleSetSongs
    }
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={{...this.state, ...handlers}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to make use of context:

```
const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light')
class ThemeProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {theme: 'light'}
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state.theme}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider>
        <ThemeContext.Consumer>
          {val => <div>{val}</div>}
        </ThemeContext.Consumer>
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

To know more about using context https://medium.com/dailyjs/reacts-%EF%B8%8F-new-context-api-70c9fe01596b